# Track changes made to PostgreSQL database table in Odoo

Tags: postgresql, model, onchange, odoo, tracking

I have created a module with the models `Employee` and `Modules`. I want to track all changes made to any field in the `Modules` table whenever the employee updates any record in it.

Comment: `api.onchange` is made for that.

Answer (score 2):

You can track the changes on the Odoo UI also using `mail.thread` module.

inherit your model from `mail.thread`

```
_inherit = ['mail.thread', 'ir.needaction_mixin']
```

add `track_visibility='onchange'` on the model fields you wanted to track. i.e

```
user_id = fields.Many2one('res.users', 'Assigned to', 
                          select=True, track_visibility='onchange')
```

it will log the user_id field changes on the Odoo UI itself.

[image]

check the `project.task` model in Odoo default model for the example.

Or You can use the module **Audit Log** from the OCA

https://www.odoo.com/apps/modules/10.0/auditlog/

Comment: What if i want to track all changes made, not to a specific field?